# How do I get the stock symbol by Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to grab the stock symbol from this [page](https://stock360.hkej.com/StockScreener/profession/tab/profile).

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://stock360.hkej.com/StockScreener/profession/tab/profile' 

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)

dfs = pd.read_html(browser.page_source)   
print(dfs)

browser.close()
```

This is the output:

```
dfs

[                     0
 0  加入至心水組合：請先登入或註冊成為會員, Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [沒有符合以上篩選條件的股票。]
 Index: [],                      0
 0  加入至心水組合：請先登入或註冊成為會員]
```

I know it's javascript and I used Selenium already. How come I can't get the table? And how do I get the stock symbol in the page as shown below? Thanks.

[image]

Additonal info: After clicking the link, choose the 2nd one from the GREEN drop-down list, then the above table will be shown.

[image]

Comment: I've checked provided URL and I see nothing similar to values on screenshot

Comment: How do I get the same view as you show in the last image? Does it only show during certain hours?

Comment: I am sorry, I updated the question. First choose the 3rd one from the GREEN drop-down list, then click on the BLUE button. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is as follows

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://stock360.hkej.com/StockScreener/profession/tab/profile'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'option')))
# select the second dropdown option by its value attribute whose value is mb
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value=mb]').click()
#wait for blue button to be clickable and click
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[href*=submit]'))).click()
#select table
table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.dt960')
#transfer html of table to pandas read_html which handles tables
df = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0] #grab the table
df2 = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1).dropna(how='all') #lose the nan column and rows
df2.rename(columns=df.iloc[0], inplace = True) #set headers same as row 1
df2.drop(df.index[0], inplace = True)  #lose row 1
df2.reset_index(drop=True) #re-index
print(df2)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I am new to selenium. Can you explain what the code does? It's very confusing. Thanks.

Comment: Added in some notes. Pretty sure there is a way to drop all nan rows and columns at same time.